# Building Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

I [followed Tutorial](https://youtu.be/9RGEhDPRqgM?t=1123) 18:44.

In Divide and add node should attach wall and then I extrude should stay stuck on walls but it's not working.

Every time I extrude the walls go further. As far as I know, its because a number is not integer.

[image]

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-stlhirgnB0)

Comment: You placed all your text inside the image description, which is not visible in the body of your post. I've edited it into a readable text, and also added paragraphs and proper punctuation.

Comment: i am newbie here dont know how this works thanks

Answer (score 1):

Object size are $0.5$ and *Math Node*(*Add*) is $1$, should be $0.5$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works, feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be converted to a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: as I remember correctly  my object (scale dimension size was 0.5) so Math Node(Add) number should be same amount number of object dimension